# public String nextLine not working as intended

Tags: java

I'm trying to complete a ticket issuing program, in which i have to ask the user a series of questions, however the program sometimes asks more than one question at a time, effectively skipping the first question before an input can be returned, here is the part of the code, that asks the questions and below the output.

```
System.out.println("Please enter date of Event (dd/mm/yyyy): ");

ev.setDate(sc.nextLine());

System.out.println("Please enter Artist/Band name  ");

ev.setArtist(sc.nextLine());

System.out.println("Please enter name of Venue for event  ");

ev.setVenue(sc.nextLine());

System.out.println("Please enter name of city where event is being held: ");

ev.setCity(sc.nextLine());
```

As you can see this shows up as this below, I dont want to ask the user to not put in spaces, that looks terrible!

> Please choose your reference number for this event entry:
>   001
>   Please enter date of Event (dd/mm/yyyy):
>   Please enter Artist/Band name (use underscore, no spacing between words):

I have even tried multiple `Scanner`s and even a final `Scanner`, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're "hiding" the part with the question "Please choose your reference number for this event entry:" from "us"? Please add it. And I assume that you're using `nextInt()` to read the input. If that is the case, then either change it to `Integer.parseInt(sc.next())` or add a `sc.nextLine()` right under the `nextInt()` call.

Comment: there no secrecy Tom, I didnt think it was that relevant, yes it is Integer.parseInt(sc.next())

Comment: *"I didnt think it was that relevant"* This question was the last one which accepted input, how could that not be relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Put an `sc.nextLine();` at the end of your code. It will **free** the buffer and not jump anymore a question. +1 and accept if it works.

Comment: that seems to resolve it, even though the user needs to press enter twice to show next question but I'd rather that than missing input.  Really appreciate your quick response, thank you and have a good one!